# No-nonsense grammar exercise book

Tags: resources

I have want to improve my writing. Mastering grammar and spelling are building blocks of writing. Therefore I concentrate on grammar first. The books I use are:
- Oxford A-Z of Grammar and Punctuation
- Oxford Essential Writer's Reference
- My Grammar and I

These books are very useful, but I am missing exercises. The grammar exercise books I found on Amazon the are of a lower level, and they seem not to have a solid structure like my books. Instead they are are littered with colours and pictures.

Can anyone recommend no-nonsense exercise books or websites that match with the books I use?

Comment: Sorry, Sjoerd, but we generally don't allow resource requests here on the site.

Comment: Due to the information JSB has provided, your question is likely going to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a look at the Longman's Grammar and Vocabulary for Cambridge Advanced and Proficiency. As an EFL teacher, I use it as a reference, and it has plenty of exercises (no pictures, I promise). You can get an idea here:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Grammar-Vocabulary-Cambridge-Advanced-Proficiency/dp/0582518210

I take it you know about the Cambridge *In Use* series - they have an advanced version:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Advanced-Grammar-Answers-Martin-Hewings/dp/0521532914/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1324938272&sr=1-1

And Cambridge also do a Grammar, with exercises for CAE and Proficiency, which might be worth a look.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Cambridge-Grammar-Proficiency-answers-Certificate/dp/0521713757/ref=pd_sim_b_1

And to blow my own trumpet, you can find plenty of exercises for advanced learners on my own website, although they tend to follow my whims rather than any structure:

http://random-idea-english.blogspot.com